# Codeblocks C Debugging

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

I've got a new challenge to return the factorial of a number.  Got ideas on how to do this, but the challenger has given some starting code - which is shown below.

Now this isn't how I would have started it (with my extremely limited experience!) - BUT I wasn't sure how system would grab some text & place within an int array - hence I tried running it within codeblocks, debugging and looking at the watch table.  However I can't see 'num'.

So I tried copying num to num1:
    int num1[30] = {0};

```
memset(num1[0],num[0], sizeof(num));
```

that doesn't seem to affect anything...

So question really is - is there something wrong with my codeblocks config (it debugs other programs and I've tried both cygwin & MiniGW) or is there another reason for this behavious?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void FirstFactorial(int num[]) {

// code goes here
printf("%d", num);

}

int main(void) {

// keep this function call here
FirstFactorial(gets(stdin));
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Read about `memset`, what it does and what parameter types it should take. Also read the warnings your compiler is probably throwing you.

Comment: This starting code has too many nonsense to even discuss it. Run away from this challenger as fast as you can. Never talk to him about C ever again.